# Find the derivative of $F(x) = x^7 \ln(x^3 e^{3x^2 -8})$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, logarithms

> Find $F'(x)$  for $$F(x) = x^7 \ln(x^3 e^{3x^2 -8})$$

Here is what I have so far:

$$(7x^6)(3x^2)$$

Comment: It would help to use Mathjax to format it so it is unambiguous and readable.

Comment: How have you gotten what you have? (it doesn't look right) You'll have to use the rules for differentiating products and compositions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:**

$$\Big[f(x)g(h(x))\Big]' = f'(x)g(h(x)) + f(x)g'(h(x))h'(x)$$

Take $f(x) = x^7$, $g(h(x)) = \ln (x^3e^{3x^2 - 8})$.

Comment: That's is what I have now: (7x^6)(ln(x^3e^3x^2-8)+(x^7). I'm having trouble with the differentiating the last term

Comment: Use $$ and type your latex inside. It helps understanding what you have done.

Comment: Apply the same thing again to $h(x) = x^3e^{3x^2 -8} \Rightarrow h'(x) = 3x^2e^{3x^2 -8} + x^2\  6x\  e^{3x^2 -8}$. And plug it to the hint. And remember that $(\ln x)' = \frac{1}{x}$.

Comment: So it would just be f'(x)h(x)+f(x)h'(x)?

Comment: That's the product rule, yes, you're using it again on $h(x)$.

Comment: but with the terms we already found?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19364/discussion-between-aaron-maroja-and-ben).

Answer (score 2):

simplifying the given term $$\ln(x^3e^{3x^2-8})=\ln(x^3)+(3x^2-8)\ln(e)=3\ln(x)+3x^2-8$$ thus we get
$$3x^7\ln(x)+3x^9-8x^7$$ and the first derivative is given by
$$21x^6\ln(x)+3x^7 \cdot\frac{1}{x}+27x^8-56x^6$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: Recall the product rule:
$$\frac{d}{dx}\left(f(x)g(x)\right)=f'(x)g(x)+f(x)g'(x).$$
Identify $f(x)=x^7$ and $g(x)=\ln(x^3e^{3x^2-8})$. Then for $g'(x)$ you need to use the chain rule ($\dfrac{d}{dx}[g(p(x))]=g'(p(x))p'(x).$) and again product rule.